# Django ORM prioritise a column with (almost) duplicate data

Tags: django, django-orm

Basic DB table is:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    type_of_input = models.CharField(max_length=10) # say "USER" or "SOURCE"
    date = models.DateField()
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    object_referenced = Foreign_key...
```

**Problem**

We sometimes have two duplicate entries in ModelA - which means the two values for the `date` and the `object_referenced` are the same, but the values for the `type_of_input` are different. This means we need to prioritise one value ("SOURCE") for `type_of_input` over the other ("USER"), in order to make sure the `volume` value is correct (as "USER" can sometimes be incorrect).

We always get the data from the (sometimes unreliable) "USER" `type_of_input`, but only occasionally get the (always correct) "SOURCE" `type_of_input`. So when the "SOURCE" type of input value is present we need to return only the "SOURCE" row and not the "USER" row

**Question**

How could we do this with the Django ORM to only retrieve one row per date (prioritising the "SOURCE" value for `type_of_input`?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `order_by()` to put "SOURCE" ahead of "USER" and then take the first result of that queryset:

```py
ModelA.objects.filter(...).order_by('type_of_input').first()
```

Another method would be the exclude "USER" sources altogether:

```py
ModelA.objects.exclude(type_of_input="USER")
```

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working, expanding on *0sVoid* answer was the equivalent of

```
ModelA.objects.filter(...).order_by('date', 'type_of_input').distinct('date').
```

This resulted in one row retrieved per date, prioritising the `"SOURCE"` `type_of_input` over the `"USER"`.

Note: There was another issue further down the line with aggregation on one of the columns that required a Subquery in order to get around SQL's `GROUP BY`.